# How to trigger alert

Tags: java, android, samsung-gear-fit

My source code is here https://github.com/jackygrahamez/MayDay

I have a **HomeActivity.java** with an onCreate method

```
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_screen);

    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    boolean startedByCUP=false;
    if(bundle!=null) {
        Log.e(">>>>>>", "START_BY_CUP");
        startedByCUP = bundle.getBoolean("START_BY_CUP");
    }
...
```

I am trying to figure out how I can tie the condition where bundle is true to trigger the multiClickEvent so that after 5 clicks an alarm will trigger. The hardware trigger is built into this

**HardwareTriggerReceiver.java**

```
   ...
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Log.e(">>>>>>>", "in onReceive of HWReceiver");
   String action = intent.getAction();

   if (!isCallActive(context) && isScreenLocked(context) 
      && (action.equals(ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) ||           
      action.equals(ACTION_SCREEN_ON))) {
    multiClickEvent.registerClick(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if (multiClickEvent.isActivated()) {
        onActivation(context);
        resetEvent();
    }
}
} 
...
```

**MultiClickEvent.java**

```
package com.mayday.md.trigger;

import android.util.Log;

public class MultiClickEvent {
public static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 10000;
private static final int TOTAL_CLICKS = 5;

private Long firstEventTime;
private int clickCount = 0;

public void reset() {
    firstEventTime = null;
    clickCount = 0;
}

public void registerClick(Long eventTime) {
    if (isFirstClick() || notWithinLimit(eventTime)) {
        firstEventTime = eventTime;
        clickCount = 1;
        return;
    }
    clickCount++;
    Log.e(">>>>>>", "MultiClickEvent clickCount = " + clickCount);
}

private boolean notWithinLimit(long current) {
    return (current - firstEventTime) > TIME_INTERVAL;
}

private boolean isFirstClick() {
    return firstEventTime == null;
}

public boolean isActivated() {
    return clickCount >= TOTAL_CLICKS;
}
}
```

I have tried creating an instance of MultiClickEvent into the HomeActivity but that did not track the clicks.

Comment: Does your `HWReceiver` receive the hardware clicks? Also avoid using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` instead so that time is still counted even when device is sleeping.

Comment: Yes, HWReceiver is triggered by pressing the power button on the actual phone. I want to press the app label on **Gear Fit** and tie that to the same power button logic. Currently the **HomeActivity** `bundle!=null` will trigger the log when the label is tapped.

Comment: I suggest you log the states of all the conditions in your if statement (section prior to calling `registerClick()` to see if any of them are not what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up tracking the clicks on the **Gear Fit** app and then sending the alarm all within the onCreate

```
        if(bundle!=null) {
        if (!hardwareTriggerReceiver.isCallActive(getApplicationContext())) {
            int c = mPref.getInt("numRun", 0);
            int TIME_INTERVAL = 10000;
            int TOTAL_CLICKS = 5;
            long delta = 0;
            Long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mPref.edit().putLong("eventTime", eventTime).commit();
            Long firstEventTime = mPref.getLong("firstEventTime", 0);
            if (firstEventTime == 0) {
                firstEventTime = eventTime;
                mPref.edit().putLong("firstEventTime", firstEventTime).commit();
            }
            delta = eventTime - firstEventTime;
            Log.e(">>>>>>", "START_BY_CUP delta "+delta);
            if (delta < TIME_INTERVAL) {
                c++;
                mPref.edit().putInt("numRun",c).commit();
                Log.e(">>>>>>", "START_BY_CUP "+c);
                if (c >=TOTAL_CLICKS) {
                    hardwareTriggerReceiver.onActivation(getApplicationContext());
                    mPref.edit().putInt("numRun", 0).apply();
                    mPref.edit().putLong("firstEventTime", 0).apply();
                }
            } else {
                mPref.edit().putInt("numRun", 0).apply();
                mPref.edit().putLong("firstEventTime", 0).apply();
            }
        }
    }
```